# Python: Keep line formatting (breaklines) while using re.substitute for template

Tags: python, templates, string-formatting

I'm taking information about points from multiple files and create new files for each point based on template. The problematic file looks like this

```
...
Point number:"Number" {
 info
 info
}
...
Point number:"Number" {
 info
 info 
 info
 info
}
...
etc
```

Number of line with information can vary.

I'm uing re.findall() to search for points like this

```
point_info = re.findall(r"(?ms)^P.*?{$.*?^};$", file.read())
```

But when i try to put it in my template, i'm getting

```
['Point number:"Number" { \n  info \n  info \n  info \n  info \n }']
```

I use .substitute to insert info into template. Template looks like this

```
Template
... 
...
...
$point_info 
...
...
```

While input code

```
d = {'point_info ': point_info }
result = src.substitute(d)
output_file.write(result) #opened beforehand
```

How can i get my output to look exactly like in main file, keeping in mind that amount of lines can differ?
(template has many other $variables, just not mentioned here)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using .join() function. 
`point_info =''.join(point_info)` 
gave me expected result